# How to change the contents of a JPanel by selecting something or by some other actions.

Tags: java, swing

Suppose I have a JList which contains some items. Now I also have a JPanel besides the JList. My aim is to display some details about the item as text on this JPanel when tje user clicks on the item in the list. 
My question is how can I make it happen such that, when i click on some other item in the list the details of the previous item in the panel dissappears and the details of the new item appears in the panel.

Comment: Please add your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle shows you how to use JList https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html . When the list changes, call your code that updates the panel. You can draw text directly into the panel using the Graphics object from paint(Graphics g) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawtext.htm   or you can add a JLabel to the panel once and then change the text in the label